# Fill ComboBox items with FieldNames from a Table?

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I'm trying to create a combo box that has the only the field names from
a table in it and not the items in that field. So for example I have a
table with 40 fields in it like Account#, Name, address, phone # etc...
I want to click on the combo box and have the option to choose a field
and not the data within the specific field. So when I click the drop
down it will show all the fields in the table (Account#, Name, address,
phone..) I've tried a few different idea's from people but cant get
it to work. I'm using Access 2002 if that helps.

Comment: Are the tables linked to MS Access? If so, a list of fields is one of the combobox options.

Answer (score 0):

An Access combobox has a option for Row Source Type of 'field list'.
Just set the Row Source Type to 'Field List' and select the table from the Row Source dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the sp_columns stored procedure for sql server to get a list of column names for a given table

Comment: thx all find it 

  for (int i =0; i<dt  .Columns .Count  ; i++)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Columns[i  ].Caption);

                }

Comment: thx all find it 

  for (int i =0; i<dt  .Columns .Count  ; i++)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Columns[i  ].Caption);

                }